# Can The One Above All be harmed?

Tags: marvel

I'm not asking if the [One Above All](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One_Above_All_(Multiverse)) can be defeated or killed. I'm asking if it can be *harmed* in any way, or if it is essentially invulnerable to any and all attacks.

Of course, it could presumably prevent any such attack beforehand, but take for granted that the attack(s) occurs.

Comment: In what scope/universe?  The [Fandom page](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One_Above_All_(Celestial)_(First_Cosmos)) lists several universes where the One Above All was killed/destroyed.

Comment: @DavidW - No, that's a different One Above All. The other One Above All (and its dark side, the One Below All) are basically the creator and most powerful beings in the Marvel Comics multiverse.

Comment: @Adamant Hence the need to scope/disambiguate the question.

Comment: @DavidW - Trivially easy to fix

Comment: @Valorum Fair, but I'm passive-aggressive about having people who should know better do the work themselves. :-P  (It's a fault, I can't help it.)

Answer (score 3):

As we learned in the [*The Infinity Conflict*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos:_The_Infinity_Conflict_Vol_1_1), the *One-Above-All* isn't actually omnipotent when the Universe becomes disordered.

Thanos undertakes a course of action which leads to its powers becoming limited, which certainly fits the description of harm.

[image]

[image]

And by the events of [*The Infinity Ending*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos:_The_Infinity_Ending_Vol_1_1), we see that Thanos has absorbed the Above-All-Others into his own being, something that it clearly considered to be undesirable.

[image]